# Flutter getter isn't specified for the class, when it is specified

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm getting

> [dart] The getter 'currentPickup' isn't defined for the class
>   PickupEvent[undefined_getter]

error on event.currentPickup:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

import 'pickup.dart';
import '../../../models/models.dart';

class PickupBloc extends Bloc<PickupEvent, PickupState> {

  @override
  Stream<PickupState> mapEventToState(PickupState state, PickupEvent event) async* {
    if (state.isNotRunning) {
      stopwatch.start();
      timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 200), updateTime);
      yield PickupState.running();
    }

    if (state.isRunning) {
      stopwatch.stop();
      timer.cancel();

      _pushPickup(event.currentPickup);

      yield PickupState.done();
    }
  }
```

When the getter is specified in the PickupEvent class and properly imported in pickup.dart.

```
import '../../../models/models.dart';

abstract class PickupEvent {}

class ButtonPressed extends PickupEvent {
  final PickupModel currentPickup;

  ButtonPressed({
    @required this.currentPickup
  });
}
```

Any idea what could cause this ?

Comment: Please add the exact error message.

Comment: The exact error is :
[dart ] The getter 'currentPickup' isn't defined for the class PickupEvent. [undefined_getter] (31, 13)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is correct. `ButtonPressed` has such a getter, but `PickupEvent` does not.

You can either add an abstract getter to the base class

```
abstract class PickupEvent {
  PickupModel get currentPickup;
}
```

or cast like

```
_pushPickup((event as ButtonPressed).currentPickup);
```

if you are sure it will be a `ButtonPressed`.

You can also do

```
if(event is ButtonPressed) {
  _pushPickup(event.currentPickup);
}
```

Comment: Great thank you for your answer, I'm not exactly clear on abstract classes and how they work yet. The funny thing is I more or less copied from this tutorial where he accesses a variable in this way when no getter is defined in the abstract class : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad#1eb4

Comment: The value gets passed as `PickupEvent` (`mapEventToState(PickupState state, PickupEvent event)`) so Dart has no knowledge about `currentPickup` because thats defined somewhere else. What I did is adding a getter without an implementation (`=> ...` or `{ return ...}`) but it tells Dart that `PickupEvent` and any subclass will have that. You can't make an abstract field, but a `final` fields is the same as a getter from the method signature point of view.