# Getter _text isn't defined for class TagColumn in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have looked at this question on Stack Overflow [Flutter getter isn't specified for the class, when it is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340077/flutter-getter-isnt-specified-for-the-class-when-it-is-specified). And I still cannot understand why my class **Practice** does not have access to the variable **_text** which is accessed from an element in the **List with type TagColumn**.

```
class Practice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PracticeState createState() => _PracticeState();
}

class _PracticeState extends State<Practice>{
  int count  = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    List<TagColumn> ok = List.generate(count, (int i) => new TagColumn());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint){
      return new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: new Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: ok,
              )
            ),
          ),
          new Positioned(
            child: new Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0, right: 40.0),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      if(count != 0 && ok[count]._text.text.isEmpty){

                      }
                      else{
                          count +=1;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_circle,
                    size: 100.0,
                    color: Color(0xffd3d3d3),
                  ),
                )
              )
            )
          )

        ],
      );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class TagColumn extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _TagColumn();
}

class _TagColumn extends State<TagColumn>{
  final _text = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final tagField = TextField(
      controller: _text,
      obscureText: false,
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Play', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      maxLines: null,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Tag",
          errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t be Empty': null,
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
      );
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2 - 40,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
      ),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          hintColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: tagField,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is not allow the user to create a new tag when pressing, "Plus," in the bottom right corner(*see the image below*) if the user doesn't enter text in the current one. In other words, if it's not empty. Thus, I am using the variable ***final* _text = TextEditingController()**, to check if the current tag is empty when pressing the plus button. If not, a new tag is created.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dart treates variables that start with an underscore as a private variable (since there is no  private keyword in dart) so in order to solve your probelm, you need to remove the _(underscore) before the text variable.

what ill do is this

1- move the _text variable to the `TagColumn` class insted of the State class

```dart
class TagColumn extends StatefulWidget{
 final text = TextEditingController(); // removed the _ so that to access it inside the Practise class
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _TagColumn();
}
```

and update the TagColumn class to reflect those changes

```dart
class _TagColumn extends State<TagColumn>{
   // final _text = TextEditingController(); <---- since the text is now in the TagColumn class not the state class
  bool _validate = false;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final tagField = TextField(
      controller: widget.text,
      obscureText: false,
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Play', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      maxLines: null,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "Tag",
          errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t be Empty': null,
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
      );
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2 - 40,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
      ),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          hintColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: tagField,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```